# Создание проекта Spring+Gradle+Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, spring, gradle

Хочу создать проект с использование Spring+Gradle+Vue.js (читал что это стильно, модно, молодежно).

Нашел несколько вариантов:

1. Создать проект , в нем 2 модуля, сервер и фронт. И там уже все делать. Но инфы как связать фронт и бек найти не могу
2. Просто в ресурсы закинуть файлы и подключить либу Vue одной строкой, но такое писать в каждом файле
3. Вообще создать 2 отдельных проекта и с помощью магии соединить vue и spring.

В общем, я потерялся, прошу направить на нужный путь

Comment: На spring.io раньше был гайд на данную тему, но они его зачем-то протеряли...

Comment: спешу Вас разочаровать, но нужный путь сможете для себя сформировать только вы сами, в зависимости от того какой уровень владения обоими технологиями Вы имеете, от того какого размера будет данный проект, от того какие еще технологические решения вы собираетесь на данном проекте применять.

Comment: В производстве часто разделяют бекенд и фронтенд на два разных проекта...но делают это не для того чтобы один и тот же разработчик в двух окнах параллельно приложение пилил, а для того чтобы можно было отдать разработку фронтенда квалифицированному фронтенд-разработчику и не парить ей мозг для бекенд-разработчика....а вам оно для чего?

Comment: магия очень простая...web-services/rest, JWT, websockets, ..

Comment: Если Вы начинающий разработчик, то я бы посоветовал бы Вам сначала неплохо разобраться в каждой технологии по отдельности, а потом уже все смешивать в кучу, чтобы Вы потом не путались кто, что, где и зачем...Можете запутать сами себя таким подходом.